# Passing a parameter to a field variable in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a mysql table with columns of subjects, their marks and rank eg. 
col 1 - eng, col 2- eng_marks, col 3- eng_rank, col 4 - math, col 5- math_marks, col 6- math_rank. I want to pass the column values as parameter from netbeans.

This is what i tried to do. $F{$P{subject}} and $F{$P{subjectrank}} in my detail band. Its not successful and i get the following error:

Compilation exceptions: com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.ErrorsCollector@9a984b  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Too many groovy classes were generated. Please make sure that you don't use Groovy features such as closures that are not supported by this report compiler.

Could someone guide me on how to acomplish this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why you want to pass them as (iReport) parameter `$P` ? Isn't that plain data ?

Comment: Anyway, parameters are referenced by `$P{subject}` and data fields by `$F{subject}`, but not both `$F{$P{subject}}`.

Comment: Yeah, parameters are refencenced that way. Lets say my datasource querry be like this, select * from rptforms_prm. In my report i have a column of marks which is to be used for all the subjects marks so I want the field value $F{subject} be dynamic. My question how do i use a parameter to point at the field that the data will be retreived

Comment: I can think of to put all "marks" columns into the report design (probably stacked at the same place) and then with the print-when expression select the one that is to be printed `$P{subject}.equals("mark2")`.

Answer (score 1):

If any one have this kind of error, they would verify the syntax of parameters, variables, ...
for example when I have : **${title}**
I have this error : Too many groovy classes were generated.
Instead of that we sould have :  **$P{title}**

[Jasper Report With error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUl1R.png)
[Jasper Report without error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L33yH.png)